# With a short term C type visa, is the allowed duration a six month stay or the visa expiry date?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

With a short term C type visa, is the allowed duration a six month stay or the visa expiry date?

Because the duration of stay is 180 days. I entered the UK on September 27; my visa will expire on 12 October. How long I can stay in UK in this case?

If I stay after 12 October is it overstay or I can stay maximum 180 days from the date of entry even if the visa expires. What is over stay in this case please let me know.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question an hour ago?

Comment: @Abdul Overstay = not leaving on or before 12 October.

Comment: You have created two accounts ([Abdul](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/104232/abdul) and [Abdul](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/104227/abdul)).  You can [merge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them, in which case you will be able to post comments on your own questions and on the answers to those questions.  You will also be able to edit your question.